# Batching and unbatching of agents based on database reference AnyLogic

Tags: database, anylogic

To make one complete ring I need three segments. Segments C1A, C1B and C1C should be batched to C1.

After batching I want to separate rings based on their names(String) in the select output block to respective delay processes.
My question is how to create a relation between unbatched and batched rings in order to complete this whole process.

[image: all model details are here]

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SOF. Please add more details to the question, impossible to answer with given info :). See here for some tips on good questions: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Comment: This question has no relation to the `batch-file` tag you used... Did you read the description of such a tag? I am pretty sure that the negative votes are caused for this reason.

Comment: Yes it was a mistake, basically i wanted to write Batch i.e block in anylogic, since i am a beginner in this so this might happened. thanks for correction

Answer (score 0):

My first question is why do you want to batch them if they get processed separately.. See my example below I think if you just release all three the segments at the same time you do not need to batch them

You will need to add a wait block ( can also be done with a queue) and then wait until you have enough of the correct batch (assuming the batch is denoted by the first 2 letters of a segment name) See code below.

[image]

This will check if there are 3 segments with the same first two letters in their name and release them from the wait block.

Then you can do what you want with them... if you want to batch set the back size to 3 (based on your example) so that every 3 units that gets released, and they will be released all at once will be batched into a new agent called Rigng.

We store the first two letters of the segment name, which will be the same for all segments being batched and use them to set the new ring name.

[image]

You can then use the Ring name to decide which machine they need to go to.

Since we then did not select the "Permanent batch" option in the batch block we can simply unlatch them again...

But I think based on your screenshot you might just want to let them go through the system no need for batching...  I am not sure...